# Only Spawn tree on flat ground

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, spawn, terrain, procedural-generation

**What I'm trying to do**
I'm trying to spawn a tree only on flat ground but **GetSteepness()** isn't working and **GetInterpolatedNormal()** also doesn't seem to be working

**The Problem**
the trees always seem to spawn on places I don't want them to like on really steep hills they do also spawn on flat ground but i would rather them not spawn on hills at all

**I would also like to eventually**
use this method whenever it gets solved to place grass only on flat grounds
but I don't know how to spawn grass and I don't think instantiate will be good for performance I would be using billboard grass for performance reasons

**What I've tried**
GetInterpolatedNormal system doesn't work FYI I've tried playing around with **Value.x/y/z** and switching the  **Steepness.x/y/z > Value.x/y/z** to **Steepness.x/y/z < Value.x/y/z**

```
void PopulateTrees(TerrainData terrainData) {
var ray = new Ray(new Vector3(Random.Range(-100, 100), 1000 f, Random.Range(-100, 100)), -this.transform.up);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
    Vector3 terrainSize = Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData.size;
    Steepness = Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData.GetInterpolatedNormal(hit.point.x / terrainSize.x, hit.point.y / terrainSize.z);
    if (Steepness.x < Value.x && Steepness.y < Value.y && Steepness.z < Value.z) {
        Instantiate(PineTree, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y - .1 f, hit.point.z), transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, Random.Range(-1000, 1000), 0, 100));
    }
}
```

}

**GetSteepness()** method I don't know what system will be more performant this way seemed to only put trees in weird areas

```
void PopulateTrees(TerrainData terrainData) {
    var ray = new Ray(new Vector3(Random.Range(-100, 100), 1000 f, Random.Range(-100, 100)), -this.transform.up);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
        Steepness = terrainData.GetSteepness(hit.point.x, hit.point.z);
        if (Steepness > Value) {
            Instantiate(PineTree, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y - .1f, hit.point.z), transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, Random.Range(-1000, 1000), 0, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

[This is a photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdoj6.png)

Comment: Why `hit.point.y / terrainSize.z`?

Comment: `GetInterpolatedNormal` returns a normal. A normal on a flat ground points to the sky.

Comment: please show how do you tried with `GetSteepness`. Take into account that it gets the gradient of the terrain at point (x,y) where the x and y values are normalized coordinates in the range 0..1. and where probably world's z is your terrain's y.

Comment: I would give a look to [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/452204/terraindatagetsteepness-usage.html) and try it that way

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void PopulateTrees(TerrainData terrainData) {
    var ray = new Ray(new Vector3(Random.Range(-100, 100), 1000 f, Random.Range(-100, 100)), -this.transform.up);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
        Steepness = terrainData.GetSteepness(hit.point.x / terrainData.size.x, hit.point.z / terrainData.size.z);
        if (Steepness > Value) {
            Instantiate(PineTree, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y - .1f, hit.point.z), transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, Random.Range(-1000, 1000), 0, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

`GetSteepness()` should return a value in the range of `0...90`

Comment: This did not stop all trees from spawning on cliffs i can still find a few but its reduced them by a lot Thanks